# C# Routing Redirect specific controller to different url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a website in C# MVC and .net automatically recognize my Home controller as root site. The problem is that I also have now duplicate urls in google. Somehow google found also `/Home/Index` . I wanted to make everything that comes to `/Home/*` to permanently redirect to homepage of website www.site.com

Simply put

www.site.com/Home/Index redirect to www.site.com

or

www.site.com/Home/About redirect to www.site.com/About

I've tried searching how to redirect specific controller in routing but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead you edit your **RouteConfig.cs** and add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

That way you can control your routes by adding the `[Route()]` attribute above each action in your controller. For example:

```
[Route("foo/bar")]
public ActionResult Index() {
    return Content("Foo");
}
```

This will be the action for **www.yoursite.com/foo/bar**

You can also use this on controller level. Just google it, there is tons of info/tutorials on MVC Attribute Routing.

Comment: So if I put 
[Route("about")] above about action.. this will redirect /Home/About to > about ?

Comment: It will not redirect, my suggestion was that you do not use /home/something at all,  instead just use /something.

Comment: You could also add multiple routes, i.e. `[Route("foo/bar"), Route("bar/foo")]`